# Apache proxying subdomain root requests

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

### Description

- Internal Tomcat server that has webapps listening on 8080:
  **"http://internal:8080/foo-webservice/"**
  **"http://internal:8080/foo-website/"**
- External facing Apache server is proxying requests for a subdomain:
  **"http://foo.domain.com/"**
- Any requests of the root of the subdomain would be proxied to the foo-website webapp on Tomcat.
- Any other requests would be proxied to the appropriate path / webapp

### Use Case A

- Request:
  **"http://foo.domain.com/index.html"**
- Proxied to:
  **"http://internal:8080/foo-website/index.html"**

### Use Case B

- Request:
  **"http://foo.domain.com/webservice/listener.html?param1=foo&param2=bar"**
- Proxied to:
  **"http://internal:8080/foo-webservice/listener.html?param1=foo&param2=bar"**

### VirtualHost definition

- Current virtual host definition which satisfies Use Case B:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName foo.domain.com

      ProxyRequests Off

      <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
      </Proxy>

      ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/foo_error.log
      LogLevel warn
      CustomLog /var/log/apache2/foo_access.log combined

      # RewriteRules
      # ?

      # ProxyPass
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass        / http://internal:8080/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://internal:8080/
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

### Attempt 1

```
    # RewriteRules
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://internal:8080/foo-website/$1 [P]
```

- Use Case A is satisfied
- Use Case B fails

### Attempt 2

```
    # RewriteRules
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/$ http://internal:8080/foo-website/$1 [P]
```

- Use Case B is satisfied
- Use Case A is not completely satisfied
- The index.html in foo-website is loaded, but none of the files in the js, img or css folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProxyPass rules match in order

```
 ProxyPass        /webservice/ http://internal:8080/foo-webservice/
 ProxyPassReverse /webservice/ http://internal:8080/foo-webservice/

 ProxyPass        /website/ http://internal:8080/foo-website/
 ProxyPassReverse /website/ http://internal:8080/foo-website/

 ProxyPass        / http://internal:8080/foo-website/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://internal:8080/foo-website/
```

No rewrite rule. Isn't that good enough ?

Comment: Thanks, I was getting wrapped up with a rewrite when I didn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use the first attempt but include the QSA (query string append) flag in the square brackets at the end of each `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: I tired: 
`RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://internal:8080/foo-website/$1 [QSA,P]`
But the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

- I think the issue with Attempt 2 (none of the files in the js, img or css folders being mapped) was a sign that my approach was wrong.
- My solution now is to redirect any requests to the root, to the **foo-website** webapp.

  ```
          <VirtualHost *:80>
                  ServerName foo.domain.com

                  ProxyRequests Off

                  <Proxy *>
                          Order deny,allow
                          Allow from all
                  </Proxy>

                  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/foo_error.log
                  LogLevel warn
                  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/foo_access.log combined

                  # RewriteRules
                  RewriteEngine On
                  RewriteRule   ^/$  /foo-website/  [R]

                  # ProxyPass
                  ProxyPreserveHost On
                  ProxyPass        / http://internal:8080/
                  ProxyPassReverse / http://internal:8080/
          </VirtualHost>
  ```
- This was not what I originally wanted, but I think this is the resolution.